# Creating conversation in Slack API using conversations.create. I cannot seem to add members

Tags: slack-api

I have successfully used the API call of [`conversations.create`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.create) to create new private channels. I have tried two approaches to adding members to this newly created private channel (conversation).

My first approach was to create the conversation passing only my member ID and then adding other members later using [`conversation.invite`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.invite). That didn't seem to work and gave me no errors.

So I went back and compiled the list of users I wanted to add and passed them as a list when I create the private channel. Neither work.

Here are examples of what I did (basically):

```
https://slack.com/api/conversations.create?name=newChannelName&is_private=true&user_ids=xxxxKCLL9,xxxxKCSNL,xxxx6P4KB,xxxxV7KR9

https://slack.com/api/conversations.invite?channel=newChannelID&users=xxxxKCLL9,xxxxKCSNL,xxxx6P4KB,xxxxV7KR9
```

Am I missing something. Is it best to add the users when the channel/conversation is created? I would rather add them in a separate call because this will allow me to add more users in the future.

A couple things to add. I am an admin. The token I am using has all the correct permission scopes assigned.

Comment: including user IDs with `conversations.invite` will only work for so called workspace tokens. which are deprecated, so you can just ignore that feature.

Comment: your 1st approach should work in general as you explained it. for further investigation please add to your question: the (redacted) reply from the API for your invite

Comment: conversations.create returns a successful creation and I am joined to that channel. The response is too large to add here. I have attempted this a couple of ways. Using is_private = true and false. Also adding only one user_ids value and multiples separated by commas.

Comment: What does this mean? Are the user_ids values being ignored for this channel type? Here is the help for this field:   user_ids W1234567890,U2345678901,U3456789012 Optional 

Required for workspace apps. A list of between 1 and 30 human users that will be added to the newly-created conversation. This argument has no effect when used by classic Slack apps.

Comment: As I said: with `conversations.create` you can only include users if you have a workspace token. That is a special type of token, which should no longer be used. So just ignore this feature when creating a private channel. You can read about this token here: https://api.slack.com/docs/token-types

Comment: I meant you to include the response for `conversations.invite` as that is what is not working for you, correct?

Comment: Sorry I should have refreshed the page before replying. I will save the results from conversation.invite also. I saved the results of conversations.create to a file in box. Here is the link: https://omnicell.box.com/s/rat2z5jlos106ffvmhn511u9rh0e6t2o

Comment: The link is for `conversations.create`, but we need `conversations.invite`

Comment: Thanks for all the help. After diving deeper into this and knowing that I should only be using conversations.invite to add the users, I have been successful. It appears that I fixed the problem by doing two things. One don't invite the person who created the channel (me), and walk away, have a cup of coffee, get a good night's sleep and try again. I am now successfully creating channels and inviting members to those channels.

Comment: I learned one other thing, you can re-invite the same people to a channel with no error. This really simplified adding people to an existing channel. I can just invite all the users and only the new ones are added. Thanks again.